# Difference between ContentPropertyAttribute and ContentProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, attributes

I hope this wasn't asked already. But i found nothing. If something exists, thanks for the note.

The title says it all i think. 
I've seen these two variants. But in my opinion it does the same. And why can i use both. Thanks for education.

```
// variant 1
[ContentProperty("Text")]
// variant 2
[ContentPropertyAttribute("Text")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the word "Attribute" when writing attributes over something. The actual class is called `ContentPropertyAttribute`. Both of your lines do exactly the same and use the exact same attribute class.